# Accessing pg-promise module in webworkers-thread

Tags: node.js, multithreading, web-worker, node-modules, pg-promise

In am in need of using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) library in Node.js. It is known that we can't include `require()` within [webworker-threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads). Although the author of [webworker-threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) posted a similar kind of question, one can take the advantage of [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to compile node-modules into a single *.js file and import using `importScripts()`.

But in documentation it is noted that requiring native node-modules into [webworker-threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) is not possible.

And my problem is, I've tried compiling a module using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) that includes `require('pg-promise')` which results in error `Error: Cannot find module pg-native`.

Is it possible to access [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) or some other native node-module into the [webworker-threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) scope in Node.js? If not let me know the alternative possibilities or correct me if my understanding about this is wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you doing this? [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is purely a server-side module, it was ever meant for any client-side use.

Comment: My application runs on **server side** not client side. **pg-promise** is server  side requirement, also that works fine with in nodejs main scope. As i am having some **time consuming business logic**  like (parsing xml and database update) i have gone for webworker-threads. As above said i cant access **pg-promise** with in thread scope. Thank you.

Comment: It has there right in the beginning: **Note**: If you would like to `require()` native modules in a worker, please consider using the process-based [tiny-worker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-worker) instead. It does not use threads, but the WebWorker API is compatible.